# where do sensitivity, specificity, recall and precision terms come from?

Tags: statistics, terminology, statistical-inference, math-history

Binomial classification accuracy metrics is filled with lot of definitions as **sensitivity, specificity, recall, precision**. Sometimes I have felt confused with the terms and I would appreciate if instead of memorizing the terms, I understand why they are called in such way.

Do someone know where such terms come from? Can someone reccommend a book chapter with the history of this terms or how they rose up to the literature?